# Error: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python

This is the code for the weather in a smart mirror I creating. I am using someone else's code and get these two errors when running the app (the app works it just doesn't show the weather):

1. ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
2. Error: No JSON object could be decoded. Cannot get weather

   ```
   def get_weather(self):
       try:

       if latitude is None and longitude is None:
           # get location
           location_req_url = "http://freegeoip.net/json/%s" % self.get_ip()
           r = requests.get(location_req_url)
           location_obj = json.loads(r.text)

           lat = location_obj['latitude']
           lon = location_obj['longitude']

           location2 = "%s, %s" % (location_obj['city'], location_obj['region_code'])

           # get weather
           weather_req_url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/%s/%s,%s?lang=%s&units=%s" % (weather_api_token, lat,lon,weather_lang,weather_unit)
       else:
           location2 = ""
           # get weather
           weather_req_url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/%s/%s,%s?lang=%s&units=%s" % (weather_api_token, latitude, longitude, weather_lang, weather_unit)

       r = requests.get(weather_req_url)
       weather_obj = json.loads(r.text)

       degree_sign= u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'
       temperature2 = "%s%s" % (str(int(weather_obj['currently']['temperature'])), degree_sign)
       currently2 = weather_obj['currently']['summary']
       forecast2 = weather_obj["hourly"]["summary"]

       icon_id = weather_obj['currently']['icon']
       icon2 = None

       if icon_id in icon_lookup:
           icon2 = icon_lookup[icon_id]

       if icon2 is not None:
           if self.icon != icon2:
               self.icon = icon2
               image = Image.open(icon2)
               image = image.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
               image = image.convert('RGB')
               photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

               self.iconLbl.config(image=photo)
               self.iconLbl.image = photo
       else:
           # remove image
           self.iconLbl.config(image='')

       if self.currently != currently2:
           self.currently = currently2
           self.currentlyLbl.config(text=currently2)
       if self.forecast != forecast2:
           self.forecast = forecast2
           self.forecastLbl.config(text=forecast2)
       if self.temperature != temperature2:
           self.temperature = temperature2
           self.temperatureLbl.config(text=temperature2)
       if self.location != location2:
           if location2 == ", ":
               self.location = "Cannot Pinpoint Location"
               self.locationLbl.config(text="Cannot Pinpoint Location")
           else:
               self.location = location2
               self.locationLbl.config(text=location2)
   except Exception as e:
       traceback.print_exc()
       print( "Error: %s. Cannot get weather." % e)

   self.after(600000, self.get_weather)

   @staticmethod
   def convert_kelvin_to_fahrenheit(kelvin_temp):
       return 1.8 * (kelvin_temp - 273) + 32
   ```

This is the code for the weather widget in the app. The modules im using are:

```
from tkinter import *
import locale
import threading
import time
import requests
import json
import traceback
import feedparser

from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from contextlib import contextmanager
```

so those are the modules that are being used.

Comment: What about printing the response texts for both `requests` calls and find out what you get ?

Comment: "using someone else's code" - ask that someone for help with their code?

Comment: @IrmendeJong its someone I don't know from a tutorial found on Youtube, Instructables, and GitHub

Comment: Okay, well then look at @brunodesthuilliers 's comment above, it seems that you're not getting a meaningful json response from the web api you're calling

Comment: What line does the exception occur? You do 2 json.loads... that would help to know which one is the culprit.

Comment: as @brunodesthuilliers says, you could print the response texts. and also response status and headers.  `print('status:', r.status_code) print(r.headers)`.   Are you sure the api key is valid?

Comment: @aramaki the errors are in three lines, but as the code is a snippet from a longer code i wont say what line they are ill just say what the line is

weather_obj = json.loads(r.text)

return_default_decoder.decode(s)

end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

this is from the traceback module

Comment: @EliotBlennerhassett i will try what bruno says

Comment: @aramaki [The error messages](https://flic.kr/p/XjqP4Z)

Comment: @EliotBlennerhassett i was trying to print the response texts but it says that r in 'r.statuscode' is not defined

Comment: Please print the whole response object (r)

Comment: so. 
    r = responseObject
right? @aramaki

Comment: @EliotBlennerhassett yes my API key is valid

Comment: @LewysGardner: 
r = requests.get(weather_req_url) 
print(r)
What is the output?

Comment: @aramaki i am getting 'weather_req_url' is not defined. by that do you mean my API token?

Comment: @aramaki i did it with r = requests.get(weather_api_token) and im still getting the same errors except the response im getting from the print response is 'Response [200]'

Comment: @aramaki i printed r.status_code and it says the status is 403

Comment: @LewysGardner it's getting difficult to follow what you are doing. A status 403 means that you do not have the rights to access the endpoint (forbidden). That response body is probably standard HTML that's why you can't parse it into JSON. Sort out why you cannot access that endpoint (it must permission related).

Comment: @aramaki I'm using darksky.net for my token and it says im accessing it because it is showing that the api is being used, the only thing that would require login or permission or anything is logging in to my darksky account but i dont think there is anything that blocks the token because it says that you shouldnt post the api into the code if its being posted online

Comment: @aramaki i am also looking at the 'issues' tab on github of the code and other people are having the same problem

Comment: @aramaki so i got a new api key and its now status 200 but im still getting an error saying not all arguments converted during string formatting with the line: weather_req_url = "(https)://api.darksky.net/forecast/<apitoken>/<lat>,<long>?lang=en&units=ca" % (weather_api_token, latitude, longitude, weather_lang, weather_unit)                 https in brackets so it doesnt form link and shorten link

Comment: Ok so ill try opening the app the status code is 200 and then suddenly it will be 400 maybe bc you only have 1,000 free calls a day, but ive only had 12... ill just try a different service

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after so long trying I found out that even though the api token is printing 404 meaning its forbidden, it doesnt change the output the part of the code that was wrong was:

```
weather_req_url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/%s/%s,%s?lang=%s&units=%s" % (weather_api_token, latitude, longitude, weather_lang, weather_unit)
```

where it was supposed to be:

```
weather_req_url = "%s/%s,%s?lang=%s&units=%s" % (weather_api_token, latitude, longitude, weather_lang, weather_unit)
```

this is because my api key is supposed to be a link so is "(https)://api.darksky.net/forecast/"

so I took it out of the weather_req_url

N.B. https in '()' so it does not form a clickable link

Comment: weather_api_token should be something resembling "0123456789abcdef9876543210fedcba".  See https://darksky.net/dev/docs/forecast for details

Comment: @EliotBlennerhassett it is